# Do expanding mass shells gain energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, cosmology, gravity, space-expansion

I've found [an article](https://www.scirp.org/journal/paperinformation.aspx?paperid=109046) which says in section 2

> an expanding gravitational system of given mass gains energy

Does an expanding gravitational system or an expanding shell of a given mass gain energy as it keeps expanding? Has this been observed?

Comment: I don't think you should take that paper seriously, or really anything published in that journal.

Answer (score 1):

The article you reference is distressingly incoherent. It doesn't clearly define this "expanding gravitational system" anywhere. It seems to reject cosmological expansion and "dark energy", questioning the "necessity" and "disposing of dark energy". It then asserts without basis that "newtonian angular momentum is not conserved" at cosmological scales, as if the laws of physics change according to scale. We know they do not.

It seems to be saying that this "expanding gravitational system" self energizes and produces a repulsive gravitational force, and the basis of this claim seems to be that equations describing an expanding universe dictate it. Seems weak to me, but that's what i think it means.